# Converting textfile with unknown encoding to utf-8

Tags: unix, utf-8, character-encoding

I need to convert a very big textfile with roughly a million lines to utf-8 with unix commands. 
At first i just opened it in Notepad++, played around with the encodings and found one that i thought works. It looked fine. But when i scrolled through the file, i found a couple thousand lines that looked like this:

ü’]žÚ‘²?ÿì§¥íE¤•DV³·±•¢‡èÓ’áÐþœõ«©*±us …,±œhÚZÂŠ§Þ

I tried every encoding there is in Notepad++, but it did not work.
I also tried the file -bi command in unix, but it just said: 
application/octet-stream; charset=binary

I then extracted two different lines from different parts of the file, wrote them each in a new textfile and tried the file -bi command on them. For the first one it said the same, for the second one it said: text/plain; charset=unknown-8bit

When i tried the encoding that i thought worked at first on the second one, it looked good, but the line looked like crap when i used the encoding in the big file, even though the first 40000 lines looked good.

I am not exactly a wizard when it comes to this, but it is important to me and i hope you could help.

I tried `hexdump file.txt`even though i don´t know what that does. Anyway i got this:

```
0000000 4eeb b6cf 0000 4b62 dd92 53f5 6364 f902
0000010 6cb1 ed9f 06a2 956b 2b98 8278 1583 857b
0000020 bb66 65c9 eb7b 1441 bad0 161b 24ec 3320
0000030 6992 cff0 737a 9498 1dc1 45ca 88f1 2da5
0000040 8e01 59e4 2acc 53bf 1568 e3e8 09ff 11e7
0000050 d7b5 18e5 6d20 c603 deb4 13ea feff 44ef
0000060 fbeb ecea 3135 01d8 7f49 5bd9 4c3e d3b4
0000070 cdf3 7556 8de9 1a52 c1b7 a8d6 d418 190c
0000080 2616 d63e 3714 e45d 1513 9ad6 14aa 63c9
0000090 8286 71cc 8221 51e8 b393 5c7b 59c2 4290
00000a0 7a36 5fd2 4222 22a5 5f9e 39d7 22d6 f22f
00000b0 7377 7541 904a e351 4010 cdf3 118b e226
00000c0 21e0 d4c5 553c 5f4e 5377 667d 3d96 a157
00000d0 2469 6edb 0c48 9d50 052a 000a
00000db
```

Comment: Are you sure it is a text file and it is in utf-8 encoded?

Comment: It is definitly a text file and it is not encoded in utf-8. That is the problem

Comment: "played around with the encodings and found one that i thought works." Which encoding was this?

Comment: It was OEM 861.

Comment: That string can't be encoded to 861, so your question is not entirely clear. Maybe post a hex dump of the relevant portions instead?

Comment: No 861 didn´t work. I don´t know what hexdump means oder does, but i entered `hexdump file.txt`. I edited the original post and added the results.

Comment: My guess is the file is not completely textual, but contains binary elements to it. Especially since your hex dump shows null bytes (`00`), which do not belong in purely-textual file (unless it is UTF-16 or UTF-32 encoded, which yours is not). So this would explain why you are having so much trouble finding a single text encoding that covers the entire file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am starting to believe the file might be broken somehow.